# Php. Вместо strip_tags просто вывести html

Tags: php

Вот код, он режет весь html кроме тегов p, a.

```
echo "<div id='sptext' class='read'>".strip_tags($text[0]->introtext,"<p><a>")."</div>";
```

Мне нужно просто вывести обработанный html. Как это сделать?
Простое удаление strip_tags или добавление других тегов в исключения крашит все...я в недоумении.

Comment: `htmlentities($text[0]->introtext)`

Comment: Что означает "просто вывести"? Что означает "крашит"? С показанным кодом что-то не как? Он сложно выводит или в чём проблема?

Comment: Это я пробовал. Вот что выводит: 
<p>Ð­ÐºÑ�ÐºÐ°Ð²Ð°Ñ�Ð¾Ñ� - Ñ�Ñ�Ð¾ Ð¾Ð´Ð¸Ð½ Ð¸Ð· Ñ�Ð°Ð¼Ñ�Ñ� Ð²Ð¾Ñ�Ñ�Ñ�ÐµÐ±Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ð½Ð½Ñ�Ñ� Ð²Ð¸Ð´Ð¾Ð² Ñ�Ð¿ÐµÑ�Ñ�ÐµÑ�Ð½Ð¸ÐºÐ

То есть вместо кириллицы, такая вот закозябра

Comment: Значит вы что-то где-то напутали с кодировками

Comment: strip_tags выводит нормально, все ок с кодировками.

Comment: Так с `strip_tags()` выводит все нормально или без `strip_tags()` выводит нормально? Или что значит: "strip_tags выводит нормально"?

Comment: Со strip_tags() текст из ($text[0]->introtext) отображается нормально. Но режет теги.
Но когда я пытаюсь его убрать, и вместо него поставить htmlentities, появляется эта фигня.

Comment: @Amigo9876 там третьим параметром можно установить encoding попробовать, но `htmlentities` Вам скорее всего предлагали в другом контексте, Вы хоть на примеры работы функции [посмотрите](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php#refsect1-function.htmlentities-examples)